# How to append dictionaries(returning from method of a class) to a list, without getting overwritten in python

Tags: python, list, oop, dictionary

How to append dictionaries(returning from method of a class) to a list, without getting previous dictionaries overwritten by latest dictionary in python

Lets say I have following classes

```
class Student:
    details_dict = {'name':'', 'age':0}

class FillDetails(Student):
    def get_details(self, name, age):
        self.details_dict['name'] = name
        self.details_dict['age'] = age
        return self.details_dict
```

I am creating an instance of FillDetails() class

```
obj = FillDetails()
```

And calling method get_details() which returns a dictionary

```
info_dict = obj.get_details('Panda',13)
print(info_dict)
print(type(info_dict))
Output: {'age': 13, 'name': 'Panda'}
        dict
```

Then I am saving info_dict to a list

```
info_lst = []
info_lst.append(info_dict)
info_lst
Output:[{'age': 13, 'name': 'Panda'}]
```

Now, when I am calling the method get_details() again with new values and appending it to the list as follows

```
info_dict = obj.get_details('Tortoise',14)
info_lst.append(info_dict)
info_lst
Output: [{'age': 14, 'name': 'Tortoise'}, {'age': 14, 'name': 'Tortoise'}]
```

The previous dictionary got overwritten by new dictionary.
How can I append dictionaries without getting over-written into a list? And also please help me understanding why it is happening, as I am saving dictionary to a variable and appending it.

Comment: May be you should check the difference between a **class variable** and an **instance variable**.

Comment: `details_dict` is class variable here which is shared among all instances. Even though you modified it for only for one instance, since it is a class variable it will affect all other instances.

Comment: Good point, but even when I changed the class variable to instance variable like 
    def __init__(self):
        self.details_dict = {'name':'', 'age':0}
still facing the same issue

Comment: Got Answer from the referred question by @Aran-Frey, I should return copy of the dictionary as self.details_dict.copy()
Thanks for helping